# Unable to fetch the data using POST method in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to post user's form data from the html to php file using the POST method but the Php file is not getting the data.

Here's the code of my html file:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="killer.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code of my php file:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The file-names are correct and both files are in the same folder.  Kindly help.

Comment: running local or hosted? http or file:/// ? you need to define "not working" here.

Comment: is this a .php file?  u tried changing the name attribute of the name field to something else eg, full-name.

Comment: Are you sure that the PHP is in the file `killer.php` and that it links up? Try opening the page by itself and see if there is an error for undefined index shown.

Comment: and the comments keep piling up, *lovely*.

Comment: Yes.  I named the php file as killer.php .  I also changed the name attribute but it doesn't help.   The php file is working, but it isn't displaying the attributes taken by the $_POST.

Comment: Yes it does say error for undefined index at line 4 when I open it on local host.

Comment: Try doing a `print_r($_POST);` and see if that works. And @Fred-ii- ikr xD

Comment: @Jek Sorry, the *"ikr"* - I don't know the lingo ;-)

Comment: @ShubamJayswal plz post the complete error

Comment: Oh damn lemme teach you some slang ;) Ikr = I know right @Fred-ii-

Comment: I tried doing print_r($_POST["name"]) instead of "echo",  but still it doesn't show me the $_POST variables.  All it shows is: Welcome ____ Your email  address is___

Comment: The complete problem is that I'm able to get the user input the "name" and the "email" field but their values are not able to pass on to the php file.   I've posted my code above.   Kindly help.